# Conditionnal Expression - Syntax error on return

Tags: python, shell, operating-system, conditional-operator

I'm launching multiple command on shell through python bu i want it to stop on fail with a message.

Here how i do:

```py
x=os.system('dpkg -i mypkg1') if x==0 else return '[Error]: Package 1 something'
x=os.system('dpkg -i mypkg2') if x==0 else return '[Error]: Package 2 something'
x=os.system('dpkg -i mypkg3') if x==0 else return '[Error]: Package 3 something'
```

But i get an syntax error on return ...

Edit: Show how call multiple os.system

Comment: `return` is a statement, and you are trying to embed it in an expression. Statements don't have values, and expressions *must* have a value. (The "exception" is the expression statement, which is a statement that consists of a single expression whose value is *ignored*.)

Comment: Don't use `os.system` in the first place. Use the `subprocess` module; its documentation tells you [specifically](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) how to replace `os.system`.

Comment: What's the point of storing `x`? You seem to want to immediately `return` on failure, there is no point of storing whether a failure occured.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The point was to get the return value of os.command.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that you want to return something if x==0 then you should write it like this:

```
return os.system('dpkg -i mypkg') if x==0 else '[Error]: Package something'
```

Comment: i can't commend on your Post because i don't  have enough rep is this what you are looking for?

Comment: `x` isn't defined anymore. This is a case where a simply `if` statement would be much clearer than trying to create a complex expression. (It's also doubtful whether the function should be returning a string rather than raising an exception, or if it should be using `os.system` instead of the `subprocess` module.)

Comment: No basically i need to run multiple command with ```os.system``` and if something went wrong with it i want a custom error message. I'll try to englobe it in a try catch so i can raise an exception